# Servlet url parameter

Tags: java, servlets

I’m working on Java Servlets web application. I have a html file “searchPage.html” in the WebContent folder. I have included the “searchPage.html” name in the welcome-file list of web.xml. Now whenever I run the servlet, the searchPage.html is run. The url is

`http://localhost:8080/HeadersTest/` .

“HeadersTest” is the name of the web app. Now my question is, I would like to add some parameters in the url following the “HeadersTest”.The parameters shall appear after the web app is run. Do I need to add these parameters in the service methods (doGet, doPost etc.)? For example:

`http://localhost:8080/HeadersTest?paramName1=paramValue1&paramName2=paramValue2`.

I’m fairly new to servlet. If someone can point me in the right direction, that will be really helpful. I have attached the screenshot of my directory structure of my web application below:

[image: Directory structure]

Update:
As I have listed the "searchPage.html" in welcome-file list of web.xml, "searchPage.html" launches whenever I run the web application. I would like to add few parameters in the url when the web app launches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the parameters to the URL means this is a GET request.
just handle it in your servlet's doGet() method:

```
request.getParameter("paramName1");
```

When you want to show URL Parameters you could just go with

```
response.sendRedirect("url with parameters");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want to access the parameter. I would like to add the parameters in the response.

Comment: Removed what I edited. Didn't fully understand that you only want to add the parameters to the requested URL. Have to think about this.

Comment: I have the "searchPage.html" file listed in the welcome-file list in web.xml. So whenever I run the web app, the searchPage.html is opened. Now I want some parameters to appear after the url.

Comment: Hello Jurgen, so I removed the "searchPage.html" from the welcome-file list. Now I'm generating the html page on the fly using the xslt stylesheet. Now whenever the user opens the link: http://localhost:8080/HeadersTest/, they are redirected to the other url which contains the parameters: http://localhost:8080/HeadersTest?paramName1=paramValue1&paramName2=paramValue2. I did it using response.sendRedirect("url with parameters"). I believe you gave this solution to me before you edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, We pass parameters in `url` if you want to access those parameters in `Servlet`/`Controller` side.

If you want to use these parameters in your controller which is nothing but your `MainServlet` class then you should pass these parameters in url. You can access these using

`request.getParameter("paramName1")`

in your `doGet()` or `doPost()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Abhijeet. I don't want to access the parameters. I would like to add the parameters in the response so that they appear in the url. I tried doing response.addHeader("paramName1", "paramValue1") but the parameter didn't appear in the url.

Comment: If you don't want to use parameters then why are you passing it in url?

Comment: I am doing that already for the subsequent requests. I just need to add the parameter for the first time the html page launches.